# How to give my C# app administrative rights? manifest file

Tags: c#, permissions, admin, manifest, rights

I'm having some trouble with my C# app that uses win32_networkingadapterconfig. The problem is that I can't use the altering functions in win32_networkingadapterconfig when I use the app on a user that dont have admin rights. I have tried to "run as administrator", but no luck. And I have tried to make a manifestfile with this content in the trustInfo part:

```
<security>
  <applicationRequestMinimum>
    <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

Enable clickone security settings are set to full trust. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: ClickOnce applications don't support administrator level elevation.

Comment: However, I have the same problem with a standalone EXE and it also doesn't elevate.

Answer (score 4):

There's a "trustinfo" dangling in your snippet.  Make it look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: Yeah that was just a c/p fail when I had to add it here, sorry!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows also won't allow you to redirect standard input/output/error across the admin/non-admin security boundary. You'll have to find a different way to get output from the program running as admin - Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8690661

Comment: Well, that would be one reason to want to use a manifest like this of course.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possible issues which I have listed in the order I suspect is most likely to less likely.

**Possible Problem 1**
What are your UAC settings? As detailed in [Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)
 if you have UAC disabled and you request administrator permissions the

> Application might launch but will fail later

**Possible Problem 2**
There could be something wrong else where in the manifest as the assembly information is required. Posting your whole manifest would help.

**Possible Problem 3**
You have added the `applicationRequestMinimum` node which is not required for UAC escalation. It may be worth dropping that and trying again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows also won't allow you to redirect standard input/output/error across the admin/non-admin security boundary. You'll have to find a different way to get output from the program running as admin - Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8690661