# How to remove admin rights requirement in build

Tags: c#, admin

Before I begin, I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457564/how-to-remove-the-run-as-administrator-requirement-in-c-sharp) but this did not work for me.

My question is simple, I am making an application that changes some files and makes some folders. It was all working great, but since today my application wants admin rights. I didn't enable this anywhere. I have tried adding an app.manifest file which says:

```
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
```

I tried rebuilding, cleaning and then building, but still it wants admin rights.
Anything I'm missing?

Comment: which OS are you using? What are the location where your app makes new folder?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, the new folder is made in the bin/Debug.

Comment: can you try giving full permission to everyone to bin/Debug folder and then try again ?

Comment: Other thing you can do is "check your code if it contains [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")] "

Comment: I have given everyone full permission, but it still wants admin rights. I could also not find any mention of the code you're referencing. Thank you for helping though!

Answer (score 1):

Two more check which you can do>>
Right click on your exe file and go to the compatibility tab and check if "Run as administrator is checked"

check in registry under HKLM if there exists any key(which contains your application location) at location SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

Comment: Thank you again for helping, Run as administrator isn't checked, and I couldn't find any mention of my program in the registry you mentioned.