# How to copy file to Program Files(86) on Win7? (c# or bash)

Tags: c#, bash

can you please give me a hand on this?
I have a .dll file say in the folder on my desktop.
I need to copy it to c:\Program Files(86)\Program Folder\ directory
I've already tried to do "File.Copy" but I can't figure out how to make it work with spaces in the folder names. Tried to put the full address in quotes - like "\"my folder\myfile.dll\"" but it also doesn't work.
Tried to write a bash file - but can't figure out how to run it through C#.

Pls help. Any solution is appreciated.
I also need to "Force Overwrite" if possible.

Comment: You shouldn't need the quotes in C#. Put the File.Copy in a try/catch block and see what the error is.

Comment: See documentation (includes example): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: 
`File.Copy(@"c:\Program Files(86)\Program Folder\mydll.dll", @"C:\mydll.dll");`

To *force overwrite* simply use:

`File.Copy(@"c:\Program Files(86)\Program Folder\mydll.dll", @"C:\mydll.dll",true);`
as per [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx):

```
public static void Copy(
    string sourceFileName,
    string destFileName,
    bool overwrite
)
```

> Parameters
>
> sourceFileName Type: System.String The file to copy.
>
> destFileName Type: System.String The name of the destination file.
>   This cannot be a directory.
>
> overwrite Type: System.Boolean true if the destination file can be
>   overwritten; otherwise, false.

As noted in another answer you may not have appropriate permissions you can try checking this by:

```
string directoryPath = @"c:\Program Files(86)\Program Folder";
bool isWriteAccess = false;
try {
    AuthorizationRuleCollection collection = Directory.GetAccessControl (directoryPath).GetAccessRules (true, true, typeof (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in collection) {
        if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow) {
            isWriteAccess = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
    isWriteAccess = false;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    isWriteAccess = false;
}
if (!isWriteAccess) //we cant write to location
{
    //handle notifications 
} else { //we can write to the location
}
```

Comment: the second `catch` block is doing the same as the first one. (probably a typo?) @DavidKroukamp

Answer (score 1):

Space in the path is no problem.

But did you take into account you need admin priviliges to copy the file? 
That means you need a [manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850768/how-to-give-my-c-sharp-app-administrative-rights-manifest-file) on the application

Also please post the actual exception, and the code. Atm we can only guess