# File IO permission error while running EXE from LAN

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-3.5, lan

I am getting following error while running my .EXE file from network.

[image]

I have developed application using .net framework 3.5.

Help me remove this error, Please.

Thnaks in advance...

Comment: Looks like you're running an untrusted application, and your system's security settings don't like that. You need to change your security settings, or tell the system that your .EXE is trusted.

Comment: Thanks, @JimMischel.
Can you tell me how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to give your application administrative rights?

Here is how to do that:
[How to give my C# app administrative rights? manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850768/how-to-give-my-c-sharp-app-administrative-rights-manifest-file)