# Trouble downloading a file from the web to a folder on my computer

Tags: c#, file-io, download, permission-denied, webclient

I am writing a program that basically uses a DAT file of countries from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ to run some analysis of IP addresses.

However if the folder in C:\ProgramData\IPChecker is not there (first time) I create it - no problem, this works.

However if the file is not in the folder - which it won't be the first time I run the program or at scheduled intervals to get latest copies of the DAT file, I want to be able to download the file from the web and put it into this folder.

I cannot post any code as the editor won't let me but its a simple DownloadFile command with URL and Path as parameters.

Where this.DataFolder is the path to the folder I have either just created OR want to copy the zipped file into e.g C:\ProgramData\IPChecker

I am then going to unzip the file so it can be used - if I get that far.

I thought these two lines of code would do what I wanted.

However I keep getting an error saying I don't have sufficient privileges to move the file into the folder.

I have manually made the folder (I have admin rights), changed the path to the root of c:\, the downloads folder and various other folders on my PC but whatever folder I am trying to download and copy into I always seem to get the same permission denied error.

I have tried pasting the whole exception in this box but again the editor won't let me save the post if I do. It's just a "Message=Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\ProxyHunter' is denied." error with StackTrace from "at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)"

Can anyone think what is going on or what I need to do to get the WebClient.DownloadFile line to work without throwing a permission denied error?

I am using .NET 4.5

Also although the exception says I am in VS 2010 (where I did create the original project) when I opened the project today it opened in VS 2012. So I don't know if that has anything to do with it or not.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I guess Account that runs your web application does not have permissions for mentioned folder. You may try to grant such permissions. To check that, can you go to 'C:\ProgramData\ProxyHunter folder, open properties window, Security->Edit>Add->Advanced->Find Now->Select  'Everyone' and click OK and select all permissions? Then retry your test. If it works - you know the reason. But remove granted permission for 'Everyone', that is security hole. You need to grant permissions to exact user that is used to run your app

Comment: Hi, I did try that granting Everyone full access control to that folder (write,execute,read,full access, everything) but it still bombs out when I debug it or run it as an EXE. Same error, permission denied. The event log viewer shows nothing extra than the error is in C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll 
Is there something special you need to do when downloading files from the web? Its a .gz file, which I then want to unzip before using.

Answer (score 1):

Right I've fixed it. Basically I was being a nob as the code I was copying from was providing a folder path as the 2nd parameter to WebClient.DownloadFile(url,path) and not a file path.

Once I changed the path to a file path and not just a folder the file was downloaded to that location correctly.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: That's what I was doing, too. Thanks for sharing your fix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to run the program from a network share?  If so the program could be restricted from writing to the local drive due to your machine security policy. Try copying the program to your local disk and running from there.

If it works locally, then I suggest taking a look at other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760814/file-io-permission-error-while-running-exe-from-lan)

Further information on setting .Net security policies can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezf53bba(v=vs.90).aspx)

Cheers

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use webclient.DownloadFile(url,directory) to download the file from a URI to my c:\ProgramData\ProxyHunter folder, as I assumed this was the secure place to use, read/write files on Win7. I have other programs/services that run and can read/write to their own folder in that directory. However I have never tried downloading a file from the web to a folder before so maybe its permissions to do with that.

Comment: I don't think it will be related to your use of `WebClient.DownloadFile` as this doesn't have any specific security attributes.  You could prove this by simply changing your program to write random data to the file.  Can you confirm you are running your program from a location on the `C:` drive?

Comment: Your `ProgramData` directory may also be restricted.  See this [MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8f2d61c7-ec19-4a7a-8d44-3624082ed5ef/access-denied-when-attempting-to-write-a-file-to-programdata?forum=windowssecurity) which appears to reflect the same issue as you.

Comment: Yes the program is on my own PC. I just granted Everyone full access to it (as the previous person suggested,  Vitaliy, but that didnt work) There is no network shares going on. Just a VS project on my Win 7 64bit PC trying to download a file to my local computers C:\ProgramData\ProxyHunter folder

Comment: Also I have another program I created which runs as a windows service and it creates, deletes and appends files (log files) to its own folder in ProgramData. This is where I thought all local program related code needed to be for security reasons in win7 as before people used to be able to put stuff all over the place. I am pretty sure that my personally granting Everyone full access on the folder is the same as that article you gave me.